# Target specific element of react-grid-layout onDrag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout

I'm trying to add/remove the class on the grid items of the grid layout that I'm dragging but it affects all the elements instead of the one I drag on and I don't know how to avoid that. Here is my code:

```
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  const handleDrag = () => {
    setIsActive(true);
  };

  const handleDrop = () => {
    setIsActive(false);
  };

 return (
      <ResponsiveReactGridLayout
        layouts={layouts}
        className="layout"
        onLayoutChange={handleLayoutChange}
        draggableHandle=".drag-handle"
        onDrag={handleDrag}
        onDragStop={handleDrop}
      >
        {widgets.map(widget => (
          <Box key={widget.id} data-grid={widget.layout}>
            <DragIndicatorIcon className="drag-handle" />
            <widget.component {...(widget.componentProps || {})} className={isActive ? 'tilt-grid' : ''}/>
          </Box>
        ))}
      </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
  );
```

Comment: Have you found a sollution for this task? Im having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout#grid-item-props

For onDrag, onDragStop, onResize etc, they have the signature (layout, oldItem, newItem, placeholder, e, element). You can specify operations on certain elements by using these in your function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).